# It was set headers and axios but Why happen cros error?

Tags: reactjs, go, redux, axios

#### Premise / What you want to achieve

- React x Redux (port: 3000)
- Go (port: 8080)
- I am making a SPA.

I run into a CROS error when hitting the Go API.
I've encountered this problem many times, and every time I think it's solved, I hit a new API.

I should have made the basic settings, but I'm in trouble because I don't know what caused it.
We would appreciate it if you could help us.

#### Problem / Error message

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at'http://localhost:8080/login' from origin'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No'Access-Control -Allow-Origin'header is present on the requested resource.
```

[image]
I encountered this when I hit the login API (post).
However, when I encountered this problem several times, I set cros on the header of api and axios side, and
Another get API avoided the error.

Also, when you hit api with postman, it becomes header
We have also confirmed that the header set in Go such as Allow-Origin is given without any problem.

[image]

#### Applicable source code

Header settings in Go

```golang
w.Header (). Set ("Content-Type", "application /json")
w.Header (). Set ("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:3000")
w.Header (). Set ("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")
```

react axios settings

```
axios.defaults.baseURL ='http://localhost:8080';
axios.defaults.headers.post ['Content-Type'] ='application/json';
```

Posting code with an error

```js
export const signIn = (email, password) => {
    return async (dispatch) => {
        try {
            const response = await axios.post ('/login', {
                email: email,
                password: password,
            });
            const data = response.data;
            dispatch (
                signInAction ({
                    isSignedIn: true,
                })
            );
        } catch (error) {
            console.log (error);
        }
    };
};
```

Code hitting a successful getapi

```js
 useEffect (() => {
        async function fetchTickers () {
            try {
                const response = await axios.get (`/ticker?Symbol=^skew`);
                const data = response.data;
                setChartAry ([... chartAry, [... data.daily]]);
            } catch (error) {
                console.log (error);
                setChartAry ([]);
            }
        }
        fetchTickers ();
    }, []);
```

#### What I tried

I tried all the solutions that hit with stackoverflow etc. Also, considering the possibility of a problem with the browser itself, we also cleared the cache.

Is it the difference between axios by get and post? And how should I debug it?

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem some time ago but I used Express for the backend, who knows this can solve your problem too.

try adding this to the axios settings `axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;`

You also need to allow the OPTIONS method for [preflight requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request)

this article might help you solve the CORS problem on the backend: https://flaviocopes.com/golang-enable-cors/

Comment: Thank you your advice I tried all however could not solve it.

Answer (score 0):

The method was validated in gorilla / mux.

```
   - r.HandleFunc("/login", app.loginHandler).Methods("POST")
   + r.HandleFunc("/login", app.loginHandler).Methods("POST", "OPTIONS")
```

We also had to deal with preflight.

```
if r.Method == "OPTIONS" {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:3000")
    w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")
    w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type")
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
        return
}
```